# How does one set the auto-logout time in mochiweb?

Tags: erlang, mochiweb, mochi

I'm looking at the source code for mochiweb and seeing numbers that test cookie expiration time that look nothing like the behavior of the server that I've inherited.  mochiweb has 111 and 86417 (a day plus 17 seconds) in source, but it looks like it only does any of that through cookie expiration and that - in test code.  (see mochiweb_cookies.erl)

The server that I'm looking at is timing out users in about 10-15 minutes, but nowhere do I see any code that is setting the cookie value, nor do I see any code path through the mochiweb source that would even allow me to set it.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1st part of your question is quite ambiguous and not clear. What exactly are you looking for inside mochiweb_cookies.erl??

Answer (score 3):

There are really two questions here:  "How is my application doing session expiration?" and "How do I set a cookie with `mochiweb_cookies`?"  Only the second one can be reasonably answered without further information.

```
Req:ok("text/plain",
       [mochiweb_cookies:cookie("session", "my-session-id", [{max_age, 86417}])],
       "you're logged in!")
```

mochiweb_cookies:cookie/3 returns a `{"Set-Cookie", "headervalue"}` pair which is appropriate as a value in the `ResponseHeaders` arguments of `mochiweb_request:respond` and `mochiweb_request:ok`.

It is of course possible to set cookies in mochiweb without using the `mochiweb_cookies` module, they're just headers after all.  Your application may be setting the cookie by handcrafting the header, or a proxy or another application service hosted under the same domain may be setting the cookie.

That being said, if at all possible you should avoid relying on cookie expiration to log out users.  The max-age is really just a hint to the browser to stop sending the cookie after that time has passed.  A browser or an attacker can always misbehave and send the cookie indefinitely.